# Ban on travel to any commonwealth country

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

How would I know that there is a ban on my travel to the UK or any other country? Is there some means such as an endorsement in the passport or the like? I ask because my Tier 2 visa recently got refused due to an invalid document. I'm guessing my agent gave incorrect details, but in my refusal it only states an invalid document.

Comment: What was the wording of the refusal? Are you sure it was an invalid document? Or perhaps they feel the document was counterfeit? If we know the exact wording, we can probably sort out if you've been banned.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered at all without more detail. An actual UK visa refusal letter would never "only state an invalid document", it would tell you which document, what they thought was wrong with it and under which section of the immigration rules you were being refused. An application so incomplete or incorrect that they didn't consider it might be returned some other way for all I know, but likely wouldn't be called a refusal and would just want you to fix the problem. Since you think you might be banned I suspect you must know more than you are letting on(?).

Answer (score 4):

Every country has its own immigration rules and punitive measures. The commonwealth does not share immigration responsibilities. That said, other countries, commonwealth or not, may ask if you have ever been refused a visa before and why. And they can share information if so disposed. You will likely have to deal with that for most of your future travels and it may lead to refusals (not bans, unless you lie and are later found out to have been lying).